# 3 WordPress Instances - is there a solution?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, blogs, wordpress

A website I work on is currently running three different instances of Wordpress blogs, all with their own set of users & permissions, plugins and themes.

Unforauntely, I don't think Wordpress Network is a viable option due to the restrictions around where sub-blogs can be in terms of urls.

Here are the url structures of each blog:

1. sub.domain.com/blog-1 (lives in web_root/blog)
2. sub.domain.com/folder/blog-2 (lives web_root/blog-2, being aliased to folder via Apache)
3. sub.domain.com/blog-2 (lives in web_root/blog-2)

sub.domain.com is a Zend Framework website to complicate matters where all requests for files that don't physically exists are being rewritten to sub.domain.com/index.php

Any thoughts on how I can consolidate these instances into one Wordpress install? Thanks.

Comment: Is there nothing clever you can do with modrewrite to fake your desired folder structure?

Comment: If there are plans to continue growing the site with more wordpresses, you could try porting everything on Wordpress MU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a huge fan of wordpress MU.  There is no problem having separate user stores, and using separate plugins.

It will make updating Wordpress software 3 times easier.

Export all of the blogs and then import them into one Wordpress instance.  The only strange one is sub.domain.com/folder/blog-2 but you can use the same apache mod_rewrite trick to redirect it to the lower folder.

Comment: I can't do that. This would imply that I need to put wordpress at my site root where Zend is running. If anything, I'd need to put the all of the blugs in /blog, but Wordpress MU will only let me create additional sites at /blog/*.